# Неправильный формат вывода числа

Tags: c, вывод, double, форматирование

Написал программу для подсчета координаты точки пересечения высот треугольника.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main () {
    double x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3; //A - x1, y1; B - x2, y2; C - x3, y3;
    scanf ("%lf %lf %lf %lf %lf %lf", &x1, &y1, &x2, &y2, &x3, &y3);
    double k_hc = (x1 - x2) / (y2 - y1); //коэффициент k высоты из точки С
    double k_hb = (x1 - x3) / (y3 - y1); //коэффициент k высоты из точки B
    double b_hb = y2 - k_hb * x2;
    double b_hc = y3 - k_hc * x3;

    //уравнения высот
    // double x_hb;
    // double y_hb = (b_hb) + k_hb * x_hb;

    // double x_hc;
    // double y_hc = (b_hc) + k_hc * x_hc;

    double x = (b_hb - b_hc) / (k_hc - k_hb); //x пересечения высот
    double y = b_hb + k_hb * x;
    printf("%lf %lf", x, y);
}
```

Выдало следующую ошибку: неправильный формат вывода.

```
--- Результат работы: размер 25 ---
3.0000000000 2.0000000000

--- Правильный ответ: размер 48 ---
 3.00000000000000E+0000  2.00000000000000E+0000
```

Попробовал написать так - `printf("%e %e", x, y);`

Опять ошибка:

```
--- Результат работы: размер 25 ---
3.000000e+00 2.000000e+00

--- Правильный ответ: размер 48 ---
 3.00000000000000E+0000  2.00000000000000E+0000
```

Грубо говоря, мне нужно вывести число типа double в экспоненциальной форме. 
Как добиться нужного формата вывода?

Answer (score 1):

См. [тут](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) - спецификатор `E` с указанием точности.

```
printf("%.14lE",x);
```

Это устраивает?